# Can we just have a header file for the inline global function and that means no .cpp file?

Tags: c++, function, header, include, inline

I have to add a global function to my program. My global function body is quite small, so I'm thinking of using inline. As we can define the body of the inline function in the header, so to confirm, we don't need a .cpp file at all? Or I'm missing something?

```
inline void foo()
{
    //function body
}
```

I mean, can we just add that header file to other files and use that global function or .cpp file is a must as per CPP standard practice?

```
#include foo-header-file
foo();
```

I'm new to all these CPP concepts. Any guidance in the right direction will do!

Comment: @Scheff - Not just since C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we don't need a .cpp file at all

`main` cannot be inline, so you need at least one source file.

Answer (score 1):

> As we can define the body of the inline function in the header, so to confirm, we don't need a .cpp file at all? Or I'm missing something?

Yes, if you define the function in the header, you don't need a source file. But keep in mind, if you edit the body of the function, then all the source files which uses your header will get recompiled. This may result more compile time.

> I mean, can we just add that header file to other files and use that global function or .cpp file is a must as per CPP standard practice?

Yes you need at least one .cpp file in your project. Source files are the ones which will be compiled, not the header files. Header files will be copied to source files before compiling so the entry point (usually `int main() { ... }`) needs to be in a source file.

Comment: Thanks, one thing, it means the function which is residing in a header file without a source file will not get compiled as well during program building?

Comment: @AadilHoda If its only in a header file, it wont. If it is to be compiled, it needs to be in a source file. That's where `#include` comes in.